# How to have certain *windows* start in different spaces during start up?

Tags: macos, spaces, desktop, login-items

Is there a way to have certain *windows* of an app open in specific spaces?

Whenever I start up my computer, all my log in items get mashed into one space.

I'm using OSX 10.7.5 Lion

**Edit:** I would like to use textedit in any space, but if I assign it to space#3, for instance, then everytime I use textedit, it switches to space#3 unless I manually drag it to the space I need. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which OS X version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Put the app on the space you want it on.

Right click on the app in the Dock and select "Options -> Assign To... This Desktop"

Then the apps should keep their assignments, even through log out and reboot.

Comment: But what if I want to be able to use textedit in any window, but there are specific .txt files that I want to always have in certain spaces?