# Multiple Desktops/Spaces: Assign specific application windows to a specific Space programmatically?

Tags: applescript, catalina, bash, script, spaces

I have seen existing questions ([Assign Application Windows to Different Spaces/Desktops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105463/assign-application-windows-to-different-spaces-desktops), [Spaces in Mavericks: apps do not remember their space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108721/spaces-in-mavericks-apps-do-not-remember-their-space), [How to have certain *windows* start in different spaces during start up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90334/how-to-have-certain-windows-start-in-different-spaces-during-start-up)) related to this but I could not find a satisfactory answer:

I would like to assign a **window** of a specific app, say Firefox, to, for e.g., space number 2 on my Mac running Catalina.

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically, using bash or AppleScript?

For e.g., the script algorithm could be:

1. Access the space identifier (if it exists) and store it somewhere
2. Access the application window identifier and store it somewhere
3. If a space is logically a collection (array) of app windows, assign the
   app window to the correct array related to that space.

Comment: Can you please add links to the questions you‘ve already looked at, and list the things you‘ve tried?

Comment: Is there a particular need to script this? It's a 2 second job to assign an app to a space. It's not possible to assign a single window to a space, except temporarily - which takes the same 2 seconds.

Comment: @nohillside, done.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I would like to assign specific spaces to contexts, like a space for coding, a space for video editing, and so on. Each space should contain app windows relevant to that context. Also, I have already clarified in the question that I'm not looking to assign an app to a specific space but an app window.

Comment: I'd have a look at what's on offer if you search "mac window manager". I'm pretty sure you have to dig in at code-level, you can't do it with Applescript. Apple forgot all about Spaces when they introduced fullscreen & it has languished unfinished ever since, I'm afraid.